# Unable to upload policy. Reason: The B2C service has an internal error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom#comments-container) and when I try to upload my edit policy I'm getting:

[image: upload policy error]

I was able to upload `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` and `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`.

I also tried downloading the existing edit policy I previously uploaded and re-uploading that and that fails too.

**ProfileEdit.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_ProfileEdit"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_ProfileEdit">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>ebenefitsdev.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="ProfileEdit" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_loyaltyId" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: @Parakh I'm gtg, thanks.  See my update below in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue.  I had the ApplicationObjectId in the ClientId field and vice versa from [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom#modifying-your-custom-policy-to-add-the-applicationobjectid).  Once I fixed that, the issue when away.

I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/2730/commits/95b53108ba1b6d2e5b559daf2c18c326ab53841d) to improve the documentation.